# How to Transfer Element Id's into Hyperlink of JSON Get Request?

Tags: jquery, json, hyperlink, jsonp

I'm trying to insert two Element Id's right in the middle of a hyperlink contained within a JSON (JSON-P) get request using jQuery. Any suggestions?

```
function doFunction(id1,id2) {
    $.getJSON("http://google.com/[id1]/[id2]?callback=?");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I follow; is this what you're looking for?

```
function doFunction(id1,id2) {
    $.getJSON("http://google.com/" + id1 + "/" + id2 + "?callback=?");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $.getJSON("http://google.com/"+id1+"/"+id2+"?callback=?");
```